# function to change given dimension of javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that keep changing with the user input.

for example:

```
user = ['a','b',['c','d'],'e',['f','g',['h','i'],'j']]
```

I also have a pointer to point where to make a change.

```
pointer = [1] change value at user[1]
pointer = [2,1] change value at user[2][1]
pointer = [4,2,2] change value at user[4][2][2]
```

Dimension is mostly not the same and can be more than 10.
Now I'm making a string then eval.
Can I write a function without using eval?

Comment: What does your function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lodash's `_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs#set)!

```
_.set(user, [4,2,1], '!')
```

Or, if you don't want lodash, you can implement this one yourself.

```
function setDeep(obj, path, val) {
    if (path.length === 1)
        obj[path[0]] = val;
    else
        setDeep(obj[path.shift()], path, val)
}
// then use: setDeep(user, [4,2,1], 'something').
```

Note that this version will throw if the specified key doesn't exist. This is also not a good example of clarity and maintainability, so you'll need to improve it, but it's a good starting point - it does what you want.

If you neet to get instead of set - use lodash's `_.get` or implement it yourself, it would be very similar to my `setDeep`.

Comment: This really help. Both ways work for me!
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the user's input is a string and not an array like in your example, because you mentioned eval, otherwise it's a completely different approach.

```
var user = "['a','b',[4,'d'],'e',['f','g',['h','i'],'j']]";
JSON.parse(user.replace(/'/g, "\""));
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for string. User is an array to store user input and I allow a nested input. Sorry that my question is not clear.

Comment: Please thank me by clicking the top arrow on the left to my answer.